# Magento2: Catalog PDF generator out of stock products

Tags: magento2

> We use free extension pdf catalog generator.
>   **https://snm-portal.com/pdfpublication-templates**
>
> But this extension generated all products also out of stock. Code is
>   full open source.
>
> Any one help how can we change to generate products only in stock?
>
> [Here is extension files](http://gofile.io/?c=Mz1hv6)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replace `public function getProduct($sku, $printMode)` function in 
`/app/code/Snmportal/Publication/Helper/Data.php` file, I'm not sure is this function for that or not, but you check with this, I have not tested, you can replace this function with following function for get only in_stock product.

```
public function getProduct($sku, $printMode)
{
    $product = $this->dataCache->getProductBySku($sku);
    if (!$product->getId() && $printMode == 'preview') {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false)
            ->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id', 'is_in_stock=1')
            ->setPageSize(1)
            ->setCurPage(1);
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $product = $item;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $product;
}
```

I hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: After replace this function, still generated all products also out of stock

Comment: Did you cleaned the cache after replaced the function?

Comment: Yes cache clear after replace